# is it possible to connect a href link in QTextBrowser to a slot?

Tags: python, pyqt4

is it possible to connect a href link in QTextBrowser to a slot?

I want to make something that looks like a link in a QTextBrowser, but when user clicked on it, it will call one of the methods.
Is that possible?

if that is not, what is a good alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found out how.
there's a signal call anchorClicked(QUrl)
that should do the trick :)